Notation for "the sum of column elements in a in the upper triangle of a matrix for a given row"
This may be a bit of a sloppy way of asking the question, but I'm interested in seeing if there is any way to succinctly write "the sum of column elements in a in the upper triangle of a matrix for a given row". Knowing that this is probably unclear, I'll illustrate what I want to say with an example.
Suppose I have a $3\times 3$ matrix of the following:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}$$
Im intrested in the notation for an operation that does:
$$\textrm{Upper Row Sum}_1=1+2+3$$
$$\textrm{Upper Row Sum}_2=5+6$$
$$\textrm{Upper Row Sum}_3=9$$
I was thinking along the lines of $\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}} a_{i(j=i)}$ where $i$ refers to a specific row element, $j$ refers to a specific column element from $\mathcal{J}$ many elements and the sum starts on the diagonal elements where $j=i$.
Is there a clearer way of writing this?

Well, the standard way to write this would be
$$\text{Upper Row Sum}_i(A) = \sum_{j=i}^n A_{i,j}$$
Are you looking for something more compact than this?

This works great. Thank you!

You could use the Hadamard product of matrices to get
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1} \odot \pmatrix{a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&k} =
\pmatrix{a&b&c\\0&e&f\\0&0&k}
$$
and then
$$
\pmatrix{a&b&c\\0&e&f\\0&0&k}\pmatrix{1\\1\\1} = \pmatrix{a+b+c\\e+f\\k} 
$$
